# What is the opposite of a 'belt and braces' approach?

Tags: idiom-requests

I want to be able to highlight that our usual preparation for worst case scenarios, in which a 'belt and braces' approach is essential, is not being followed in certain areas.

Is there an idiom I can use that conveys the optimism of hoping that, in the absence of both belt *and* braces, the metaphorical trousers (BrE) or pants (AmE) will still remain where they should be ?

> "*Our usual preparation for worst case scenarios, in which a 'belt and braces' approach is essential, is not being followed in certain areas and I fear that, instead, we are having to accept a [ _ _ _ _ _ _ ] approach.*"

Comment: "Scattergun", perhaps? Although this implies a complete lack of preparation, rather than a lack of contingency planning.

Comment: The “hope and pray sagger approach”

Comment: [The “pants on the ground approach”](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tMwhl4IrPNc)

Comment: @Jim _Pants on the Ground_ approach; I like it.

Comment: @Jim ... or "plug and pray".

Comment: @Mick - I don’t get the *plug* reference.  Unless... NO... You couldn’t mean....   Eeeew

Comment: @Jim It's how some people refer to "plug and play".

Comment: @Mick - Yeah I recognize that, but I don’t see how it works with the pants analogy.

Comment: Sagging trousers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a belts and braces approach, you'd be *flying by the seat of your pants*.

> **Fly by the seat of one's pants**
>   Decide a course of action as you go along, using your own initiative and perceptions rather than a predetermined plan or mechanical aids.
>   [- The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/139400.html)

It conveys the optimism you asked for, references the piece of clothing you noted, and brings with it a whiff of the risk involved in doing things that way:

> To fly by the seat of your pants is pretty tricky especially since it means you’re doing something difficult without the necessary experience or ability to achieve success.  The phrase comes from back in the day when airplanes — being very basic without all the fancy gadgetry planes have today — were flown by pilots who reacted to the feel of the plane.
>   [- Elyse Bruce, Historically Speaking](https://idiomation.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/fly-by-the-seat-of-your-pants/)

Answer (score 2):

If there is not a perfect complement, perhaps we can resolve this by staying true to the metaphor otherwise, e.g. "situations where we might end up caught with our trousers down" ;) Otherwise maybe "hanging on by a thread" could find it's way into your discourse. Likewise, "Quite frankly there are some situations wherein our safety is not assured by belt and braces, but is rather hanging on (has us hanging by) tenter hooks." If done right, "waiting for the other shoe to fall" might work.

Otherwise, there is also "on a wing and a prayer", keeping one's fingers crossed and hoping for the best, devil-may-care, happy-go-lucky, harum scarum, sans souci. Maybe create a cheesy acronym for one of these "approaches" and then reveal the underlying phrase (?)